# unable to work with cgi on ubuntu16.04 debian

Tags: apache2, python-2.7, cgi

I'm a newbie and trying to create the following simple cgi script and stored it in /usr/lib/cgi-bin/hello.py:

```py
 #!/usr/bin/python
 print "Content-type: text/html"
 print
 print "<html>"
 print "<center>Hello, Linux.com!</center>"
 print "</html>"
```

Also, I have add the following code to the /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf:

```xml
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
  Options +ExecCGI
  AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory>
```

and tried to run on browser by http://usr/lib/cgi-bin/hello.py. It's not working

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally, [This](http://tasdikrahman.me/2015/09/30/Running-CGI-Scripts-on-Apache2-Ubuntu/) article worked for me.

Instead of modifying '/sites-available/000-default.conf', I write the following code in '/etc/apache2/conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf':

```
   ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
         <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin/">
              AllowOverride None
              Options +ExecCGI 
         </Directory>
```

Also, I saved the hello.py in /var/www/cgi-bin folder and then open the file in the browser.